# HTML CSS Table with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, border-radius

I have little problem with my table. It is stylized by classes. One for TABLE that makes rounded corners and changes background to grey. The other is to make rest of the table white and I assign it to TBODY.
After second class is asigned, bottom-left and bottom-right corners are no longer rounded.

```
<table align=center class="grey">
  <thead>
    <tr height=50>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="white">
    <tr height=50>
      <td>row two</td>
      <td>row two</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height=50 class="white">
      <td>row three</td>
      <td>row three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

table.grey {
    background: #F6F2F5;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.white {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  padding: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Giving class to TR of each row gives same result as to TBODY. I'm dumb.
https://jsfiddle.net/2tm4z90b/8/

Comment: tbody cannot be styled, it is not supposed to be seen, it is a semantic wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tbody` cannot really be styled , it is part of the structure of a table and is not supposed to be seen, nor styled unless you reset its display but that will break your table-layout.

Option are

- to set the radius only on the table and use overflow.
- fake the border via a box-shadow if needed, so it follows the rounded shape

Possible example:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

table.grey{
    margin-top:3em;
    background: gray;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 3px red;/* instead border */
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow:hidden; /* hide overflowing cells */
}
.white tr {
  background: #bee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<table align=center class="grey">
  <thead>
    <tr height=50>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="white">
    <tr height=50>
      <td>row two</td>
      <td>row two</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height=50>
      <td>row three</td>
      <td>row three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: overflow:hidden made it work with my code. Didnt even need to use box-shadow. Thank you, I owe you man ^^

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

```css
table {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table thead {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table align=center class="grey">
  <thead>
    <tr height=50>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="white">
    <tr height=50>
      <td>row two</td>
      <td>row two</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height=50 class="white">
      <td>row three</td>
      <td>row three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not the only table in here, so cant use your css

Comment: You can use it for some tables or one table.
Just adjust the css width .class , #id or table in an element.

Comment: You fixed code that was in conflict by deleting it. That's not fix at all.